# PHP cURL appears to be caching or something

Tags: php, curl

Basically I have a function that does a cURL execute to an api for orders. I have an array of order ID's and when I loop through orders and call on function the response I get from the cURL request is the same.

Basically I pass in variable 1000 and creates an xml string. The cURL response is correct for order 1000. Then next item in loop passes in 1001. The xml is created correctly but the response is still from order 1000. I have no clue why this is happening.

Comment: curl doesn't cache anything, except some metadata like cookies. maybe the api doesn't allow more than 1000.

Comment: Use Wireshark or similar to see what's actually on the network.

Comment: Hit the API with a REST client on Chrome and make sure the response is correct.

Answer (score 0):

No code posted is not good.

It would help to know HOW you know the second request has the 1000 data.

I am suspecting an error on the second request.

XML value is still 1000?

```
foreach($orders as $number){

  $data = '';

  $ch = curl_init();
     ...
  $data = curl_exec($ch);

  if (curl_errno($ch)){
    $data .= 'Retreive Error: ' . curl_error($ch);
  }

}
```

Some troubleshooting cURL options:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 100);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,100);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING,"");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
```

**Get results**

```
$data = curl_exec($ch);
$skip = intval(curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE)); 
$responseHeader = substr($data,0,$skip);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
$requestHeader = $info['request_header'];
$info = var_export($info,true);
echo "<pre>$requestHeader \n\n $responseHeader\n\n $info \n $data";
```